# XLabs CalendarView month selection

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.labs

Is anyone having trouble with the CalendarView component from XLabs? I have written the XAML code below, tried to run it on my Android device, and it displays just fine, only there's no way to change the current month (I'm expecting a swipe should work), nor can I see any navigation arrows.

Anyone got any idea what's going on?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Controls;assembly=XLabs.Forms"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestXAML"
             x:Class="TestXAML.MainPage"
             Padding="10">

    <controls:CalendarView
            x:Name="calendarioConsultas"
            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
            ShowNavigationArrows="True"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            NavigationArrowsColor="Black"
        />
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved it by setting MinDate parameter to 01/01/1970. Turns out that navigation doesn't work unless you specify MinDate or MaxDate.